# how to list objects json into php?

Tags: php, json

I need help listing objects in my JSON through PHP.

JSON:

```
{"empregados":[{"nome":"Jason Jones", "idade":38, "sexo": "M"}, {"nome":"Ada Pascalina", "idade":35, "sexo": "F"}],
 "gerentes":[{"nome":"Artur Bezerra", "idade":32, "sexo": "M"}, {"nome":"Fernanda Lima", "idade":35, "sexo": "F"}]
}
```

I want list the objects(empregados,gerentes). but imagine I do not know their names. How to list them in php? thanks

Comment: Normally I would say: Decode the json and loop over the resulting array. However, what you have posted is not valid json. Is that really your input?

Comment: well, it's _almost_ valid json though, just quote _empregados_ and _gerentes_

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Use a `foreach` loop with key and value. Do this:

your JSON file (test.json):

```
{
    "empregados": [
        {
            "nome": "Jason Jones",
            "idade": 38,
            "sexo": "M"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Ada Pascalina",
            "idade": 35,
            "sexo": "F"
        }
    ],
    "gerentes": [
        {
            "nome": "Artur Bezerra",
            "idade": 32,
            "sexo": "M"
        },
        {
            "nome": "Fernanda Lima",
            "idade": 35,
            "sexo": "F"
        }
    ]
}
```

PHP:

```
$json = file_get_contents("test.json");
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj as $name => $blob){
     echo $name;
     var_dump($blob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what are you trying to achieve. But here if you wish to convert json into array:

```
$json = '{
 "empregados":[{"nome":"Jason Jones", "idade":38, "sexo": "M"}, {"nome":"Ada Pascalina", "idade":35, "sexo": "F"}],
 "gerentes":[{"nome":"Artur Bezerra", "idade":32, "sexo": "M"}, {"nome":"Fernanda Lima", "idade":35, "sexo": "F"}]
}';

$result1 = json_decode($json); 

$result2 = json_decode($json,TRUE); //associative arrays.
```

you can read here to learn more about it http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php